# Creating terminal application on gnome3 dock with the dots

Tags: gnome3, gnome-terminal

I want to create an item in the dock so that when I click, it creates a terminal into another computer.  So I did something like this: in `.local/share/applications/XXX.desktop` put

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XXX
Comment=ssh to XXX
Exec=gnome-terminal --title=XXX -- ssh XXX.com
Icon=gnome-terminal
Type=Application
Terminal=false
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=xdiagnose
```

And then I made it a favorite using "Activities".  The problem is this.  When I click on it, it puts a red dot to the left of a different terminal icon, not the icon for this entry.  So I don't know how many instances of this application I have open.

Comment: I found a solution.  I switched to mate instead of gnome.